# How can I cancel onblur in onkeydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using a rad Textbox in my asp.net page. I have onblur event. When I press shift and tab onKeydown  I changed the focus by code, but I don't want fire onblur.
How can I cancel on blur from onkeydown?

Comment: Some code please....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery than you can use .stop() method before performing any operation in onkeydown event. If you are not using jQuery than i suggest you to use jQuery. It is very light weight than ASP controlls.